# Can I programmatically silence Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a Rake task that depends on Rake::PackageTask. I need the output from my own task in our logs but I don't need 1000+ lines of output from the package task.

Is there any way I can silence Rake::PackageTask? Or is there a way I can programmatically silence any task, without having to specify `rake --silent`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress Output in Rake Task db:schema:load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079436/suppress-output-in-rake-task-dbschemaload)

Comment: @ManuelMeurer I was going to say it's not but the answers would fit here. The initial problem statement sounded different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect logs to /dev/null before calling the silent rake task. And then restore them back..

```
dev_null = Logger.new("/dev/null")
Rails.logger = dev_null
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = dev_null
Rake::Task['blah_blak'].invoke

#then restore the logger back
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but oh well... :)