# Suppress Output in Rake Task db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

How can you suppress the output of db:load:schema? Running

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

with the `-s`, `-q`, or even `VERBOSE=false` options makes no difference in the output; the same "create_table... add_index..." garbage that I don't want to see appears. I'm invoking this from inside a custom Rake task and I don't want the user to see all of this every time.

**UPDATE:**

I solved the problem with some guidance from @Deefour by using:

```
system "bundle exec rake db:schema:load -s RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} >NUL"
```

*`>NUL` is for Windows machines, Unix-based can use `> /dev/null`.*

rather than

```
Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
```

as I had been doing in my custom task. Note that this solution is specific to Windows machines. For Unix-based machines I imagine you should be able to use the accepted solution below.

Comment: How are you running the above command in your rake file?

Comment: Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke

Comment: I found using a separate `system` call out was quite slow, so take a look at using `quietly` or `silence_stream` as @lightswitch recommends.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a cleaner solution that works cross-system:

```
silence_stream(STDOUT) do
  # anything written to STDOUT here will be silenced
  Rake::Task["db:schema:load"].invoke
end
```

also

```
quietly do
  # anything written to STDOUT or STDERR here will be silenced
  Rake::Task["db:schema:load"].invoke
end
```

I prefer `silence_stream(STDOUT)` to`quietly` because it will still allow error messages written to `STDERR` to be shown, which will be helpful when the rake command starts to act up.

References: [silence_stream](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Kernel/silence_stream), [silence_warnings](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Kernel/silence_warnings), & [quietly](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Kernel/quietly)

Comment: Useful when testing rake tasks too. Makes output much cleaner.

Comment: both 2 are deprecated in rails 4.2 because they are not thread safe

Comment: deprecated in Rails 5

Comment: If these are both deprecated, is there a preferred alternative? I still find `silence_stream` very useful for muting chatty rake commands.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling the task with `Rake::Task['...'].invoke`, you can run the command in a subshell, redirecting output to `/dev/null`.

```
system "bundle exec rake db:schema:load > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

Comment: When I did that, instead of the output of db:schema:load, it displayed "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", and `db:schema:load` did not run.

Comment: Can you add to your Question the rest of the rake task that the `db:schema:load` is executing within?

Comment: Reading up on `/dev/null`, I'm realizing it might be helpful for you to know I'm on a Windows machine, not Unix-based. :P

Comment: I solved my problem by using `system "bundle exec rake db:schema:load -s RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} >NUL`, but your answer led me in the right direction, so I marked it correct.